# Upgrade Visual Studio 2008 for C# programming?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008

Visual studio 2008 has only basic projects in new project window as shown in the screenshot, Is there any way to add C# plugin to the visual studio. [window Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SZ8yM.png) and 
[Version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0xiyI.png)

Comment: Did you include the c# components while installing VS?

Comment: Can you post a screenshot showing the exact version of VS you have installed (from Help -> About) - there were something like 10 different versions, each of which had different feature-sets. Finally - VS2008?!!! That's 4 versions behind, and almost 10 years old...

Comment: I was using an older version. Now its updated. Thanks all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like [Business Intelligence Development Studio](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173767(v=sql.105).aspx) special version of VS. Get normal VS. If you don't need 2008 beeter download VS 2015 eg free [community](https://www.visualstudio.com/pl-pl/products/visual-studio-community-vs.aspx) version.

Comment: Thank you  @BWA. I have installed Visual Studio 2015 version.